# How to inherit style of AlertDialog buttons

Tags: android, button, styles

I wanna make style of my buttons at fragment like AlertDialog, how can I do it
Which style I should inherit or set for my buttons

My styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Add some pictures of what they currently look like and what you want them to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example of how i have done this in an app. You need to set an alertDialogTheme in your AppTheme. You also can apply styles to the buttons as well. Here's an example using your code.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButton</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButton</item>
</style>

<style name="NegativeButton"
       parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="PositiveButton"
       parent="android:Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/green</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Why do you think that android:textColor are holo_green_dark ? There is (at AlertDialog) some green color but I wanna get native color not set in manualy

Comment: It was just an example of what you can customise, you can put whatever colour you want in or just remove it to use global.

Comment: No, I wanna make new button like default AlertDialog not customize AlertDialog button and after that do the same with another one button. My question is which color or style is using by default, and how to set it to another element

Comment: You could create a style and set it to the button via xml, but obviously you'd have to do that every button you would want to style.